# Updating a belief using a particle filter

Tags: particle-filter, belief-propagation

I am using a particle filter to update a *belief* (the context is the POMCP algorithm found in Silver & Veness, "Monte-Carlo Planning in Large POMDPs"). A belief is represented as a probability mass function over states $x$ in a state-space $\mathcal{X}$. Let us denote the belief by $p(x)$. Assume that we do not know $p(x)$ precisely, but we have approximated it by a set of $K$ particles. Call this approximate belief $p_a(x)$.

Let us have access to *inputs* $u$ from some space of inputs $\mathcal{U}$. The inputs cause the current state to probabilistically transition to a new state $x'$ and generate a resulting *observation* $o$ from a space of observations $\mathcal{O}$.

Assume that we have a *generative model* $\mathcal{G}$ -- the generative model takes as input a state $x\in\mathcal{X}$ and an input $u\in\mathcal{U}$ and generates a sample consisting of a next state $x'$ and observation $o$.

Let the current (approximate) belief be $p_a(x)$ and assume that we have applied an input $u_r\in\mathcal{U}$ and received an observation $o_r$. We wish to form an approximate updated belief, called it $p'_a(x)$. The procedure for updating the belief, for a given input $u$, is as follows:

> 1. Sample $x$ from $p_a(x)$
> 2. Use $x$ and the given input $u_r$ to generate a sample: $(x',o)\sim\mathcal{G}(x,u_r)$
> 3. If the sample observation $o$ is equal to the observation $o_r$, then *accept* the new state particle $x'$ by adding it to the updated
>      belief approximation $p'_a(x)$.
> 4. Repeat until $K$ particles have been added.

This procedure usually works well. We run into issues; however, when the received observation $o_r$ is very rare, making it unlikely that a particle will pass the $o == o_r$ test and causing the procedure to run a very long time (possibly never successfully adding $K$ particles).

**Question:** Is there a way to approximate the above procedure? Specifically, given an $\epsilon$, can we *accept* a particle if the received observation is "close enough" to the sample observation (defined by some metric, $d(o,o_r)<\epsilon$)?

I'm unsure if such an approach has been proposed in the past (I'm not even sure how to define an appropriate $d()$).

Comment: i think it's more common for particle filters to not simulate observations $o$ at all. Rather, the simulated $x'$ will have a weight which depends on how likely it would've generated some observed data. With these weights you have the option of resampling, which duplicates particles with high weights, and transformed weighted samples into unweighted ones

Comment: @Taylor Thanks for the comment! I agree that a typical way is to compute weights dictated by likelihoods. The benefit of the belief update in the original post is that it does not require an explicit model of the POMDP (only a generative model). The weights you refer to in your comment would require an explicit model to compute (as far as I understand). I suppose I am inquiring if there is a way to obtain an approximate belief update without requiring an explicit model of the problem. My question is a guess at how that may be done.